# How to make my Makefile compatible with Cygwin? (install: invalid user ‘root’)

Tags: software-installation, make, cygwin

## I have written a very simple `Makefile`

```
$ cat Makefile

install_path=/usr/local/bin
script_name_1=encrypt-file-aes256
script_name_2=decrypt-file-aes256

.PHONY: install
.PHONY: uninstall

install:
        install -m 0755 -o root -g root -t $(install_path) $(script_name_1) $(script_name_2)

uninstall:
        rm $(install_path)/$(script_name_1) $(install_path)/$(script_name_2)
```

---

It works like a charm on Linux Mint 18.3 I have tested it on.

## But not in `Cygwin`; this is what I get as an error

```
$ make install

install -m 0755 -o root -g root -t /usr/local/bin encrypt-file-aes256 decrypt-file-aes256
install: invalid user ‘root’
make: *** [Makefile:9: install] Error 1
```

---

I know there is no `root` user in `Cygwin`, but have no idea how to fix it.

How to generalize the `Makefile` for it to work in `Cygwin` as well as on Linux?

---

## Important comments integrated and answered here

1. What happens if you drop the `-o` and `-g` options completely on the `Cygwin` system?

   Then it works well, but the user and group would be wrong on a Linux system, I suppose.
2. Hard-coding a user and group name seems like a bad idea.

   I admit I did not think of that, and when I now contemplate on it, I think that too.
3. I would recommend that you don't hard-code the installation path.

   This is a lovely idea, and yes, I agree, let the user decide where he installs it.
4. How are you invoking this `Makefile` under Linux?

   As normal user with `sudo`, i.e. `sudo make install`.
5. If you get line 9 to work outside of `make`, then it will work. It is not a `make` problem.

   I know it is not a `make` problem. I just did not know how to generalize the `Makefile` for it to work in `Cygwin` too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example of `Cygwin` compatible `Makefile`:

```sh
DESTDIR?=/usr/local/bin
install_path=$(DESTDIR)
USER_ID=$(shell whoami)
GROUP_ID=$(shell id -gn)
script_name_1=encrypt-file-aes256
script_name_2=decrypt-file-aes256

.PHONY: install
.PHONY: uninstall

install:
    install -m 0755 -o $(USER_ID) -g $(GROUP_ID) -t $(install_path) $(script_name_1) $(script_name_2)

    # with long options together with verbosity turned on it might be better for users
    #install --verbose --mode=0755 --owner=$(USER_ID) --group=$(GROUP_ID) --target-directory=$(install_path) $(script_name_1) $(script_name_2)

uninstall:
    rm $(install_path)/$(script_name_1) $(install_path)/$(script_name_2)
```

When you want to install at any other location you can override the variable `DESTDIR` or provide one in the `Makefile`.

When you run the script as `sudo` in `GNU/Linux` the `USER_ID` is set as root.

**Note:** Currently verified it on `GNU/Linux`.

**Editor's Notes:**

1. Verified in `Cygwin`.
2. Changed the way `USER_ID` and `GROUP_ID` are assigned to standard `shell` builtin.
3. Added long options version with verbosity, in a comment.
4. If you want to change the destination, you can simply invoke, for example:

   ```sh
   DESTDIR=/desired/target/directory/ make install
   ```

Answer (score 0):

The is not a problem of the `Makefile`, but a problem caused by the fact that your `install` program is incompatible with Cygwin.

If you like to have portable build systems that works on platforms without `root` user, you need a *better* `install` program that is able to detect whether the current user is able to change the ownership of files to the desired user.

I recommend to have a look at the script `conf/install-sh` in the [`schilytools` package](http://sourceforge.net/projects/schilytools/files/).

It has been written to support `Cygwin` and the script is free.